# html search form - align submit button

Tags: html, css

I have html search form - input and button.

Also I have Search title - h2 . But if I remove h2 title I have problem with button vertical-align.

html:

```
<h2 class="widget-title">Search</h2>
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="#">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." value="" >
    <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Css:

```
.widget-title {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

#searchform input {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#searchsubmit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 59px;
  right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Is it possible to align button with and without search title (h2) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use absolute positioning here, relative will be OK. `position: relative` and `display: inline` will solve the problem. And here is the working 
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kphgcp63/1/).

The markup is OK with  `<h2 class="widget-title">Search</h2>` and without.

Comment: @name name2, is this solution OK for you?